# Remover um usuário de um grupo no AD utilizando .net + powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

Olá, eu estou tentando remover usuários de um grupo no AD a partir de um script PowerShell, dentro de uma aplicação asp.net MVC. Possuo um script e função semelhante para adicionar um usuário no AD, porém não está funcionando a remoção dos usuários.

Segue o meu script e minha funções: 
Script PowerShell:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$NomeGrupo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [String]$NomeUsuarioGrupo
)

if (!(Get-Module ActiveDirectory)) {
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory
}

$NomeGrupo = "$NomeGrupo"
$NomeUsuarioGrupo = "$NomeUsuarioGrupo"
$DomainName = "LDAP://DC=tcu,DC=gov,DC=br"


Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $NomeGrupo -Members $NomeUsuarioGrupo
```

Função:

```
public void RemoveUser()
        {          
            foreach (log obj in db.Logs)
            {
                DateTime? _dataVencimento = DateTime.Parse(obj.DataVencimento);
                bool ts = _dataVencimento <= DateTime.Now;                               

                if (ts == true)
                {
                    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        // Add the script to the pipeline
                        powershell.AddCommand(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Powershell\\Remove-User-Group.ps1");
                        // Add the parameters to the script based on the values entered by the user
                        powershell.AddParameter("NomeGrupo", obj.NomeGrupo);
                        powershell.AddParameter("NomeUsuarioGrupo", obj.NomeUsuarioGrupo);

                        try
                        {
                            // Attempt to invoke the pipeline
                            var results = powershell.Invoke();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            // Catch exception and display within validation error summary
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Um erro aconteceu na chamada da função" + e);
                            //return View(obj);
                        }
                        // Check for PowerShell errors - these errors will not be caught within the Try-Catch
                        if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var error in powershell.Streams.Error)
                            {
                                // Add each error to the validation error summary
                                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.ToString());
                            }

                        }
                    }                  
                } else
                {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            }
        }
```

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda de todos.

Comment: E qual é o erro?

Comment: O sistema não apresenta nenhum erro, apenas os usuários continuam no grupo dentro do AD.

Comment: E executando direto do powershell?

Comment: Executando direto do powershell funciona.

Comment: não é nivel de permissão? tipo abre o PS como Admin, mas na aplicação está usando uma conta sem essa elevação?

Comment: Estou executando o visual studio como administrador, com a mesma conta eu executo o powershell. E a função de adicionar um usuário em um grupo do AD funciona pelo visual studio.